# How to keep no return (zero rows) in a concatenation loop?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, concatenation

I am using a code for a query, sometimes the input goes and there is no return (basically it does not find anything so the return is an empty row) so it is empty. However, when I use `pd.concat`, those empty rows disappear. Is there a way to keep these no return rows in the loop as well so that when I use that I can have empty rows on the final `output.csv`?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from dl import authClient as ac, queryClient as qc 
from dl.helpers.utils import convert

import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook('/Users/somethingfile.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet 1']


df = pd.DataFrame([],columns = ['col1','col2',...,'coln'])

for row in range(3, sheet.max_row + 1): 
    a0, b0, r = sheet.cell(row,1).value, sheet.cell(row,2).value, 0.001
    query = """
    SELECT a,b,c,d,e FROM smthng
      WHERE q3c_radial_query(a,b,{:f},{:f},{:f}) LIMIT 1
    """.format(a0,b0,r)
    response = qc.query(sql=query,format='csv')
    temp_df = convert(response,'pandas')
    df = pd.concat([df,temp_df])

df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific question, it works if you check if `temp_df` is empty or not in each step and make it a DataFrame of NaNs if it is empty.

Another note on the implementation is that, concatenating in each iteration will be a very expensive operation. It is much faster if you store the `temp_df`s in each iteration in a list and concatenate once after the loop is over.

```py
lst = []  # <-- empty list to fill later
for row in range(3, sheet.max_row + 1): 
    a0, b0, r = sheet.cell(row,1).value, sheet.cell(row,2).value, 0.001
    query = """
    SELECT a,b,c,d,e FROM smthng
      WHERE q3c_radial_query(a,b,{:f},{:f},{:f}) LIMIT 1
    """.format(a0,b0,r)
    response = qc.query(sql=query,format='csv')
    temp_df = convert(response,'pandas')

    if temp_df.empty:
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan])
    lst.append(temp_df)
    
df = pd.concat(lst)   # <-- concat once
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, this really made it run faster and produces the exact result I need!

Answer (score 1):

So, as far as I understand, the problem is that when "temp_df" is empty you want to add a blank row. You should be able to do that using the .append() method, appending an empty Series().

```
if len(temp_df) == 0:
    temp_df=temp_df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)
#Then concat...
```